# How can I configure Jersey to automagically handle POJOs when using a custom json mime type?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I'm currently working on a project that uses Jersey 1.8 to provide a RESTful API. The customer has defined their own MIME type for JSON data which is different from application/json. I find that all the nice automagic data binding features (JAXB, POJO-based, ...) don't work because of this.

Is there a way to set a specific MIME type string to be treated as JSON by Jersey?

Answer (score 0):

in JAX-RS, you can specify the MIME type:

```
@POST
@Consumes("<client's MIME type>")
public void postClichedMessage(String message) {
    // Store the message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` (i.e. [JAX-RS Entity Providers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html)) to handle any combinations of Java type / MIME type that Jersey does not support out of the box.

The link I posted is for the latest Jersey release. You might try finding the docs for your particular version so you don't end up using some feature that was not supported in the older release.